Android jetpack navigation deeplink priority
I'm experiencing an unexpected behaviour when dealing with deeplinks using Jetpack Navigation deep links.
The Url's I want to open in the app are:

"https://(...)organisation/3679-dance-company-058/product/132"
"https://(...)organisation/3679-dance-company-058"

When I try the first link it works as expected (opens the organisation screen on the app). However, when opening the second link it still opens the organisation screen and not the product screen.
I have there 2 deeplinks
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/productSeoDeeplink"
    app:uri=".*/product/{productId}-.*" />

<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/organisationSeoDeeplink"
    app:uri=".*/organisatie/{organisationId}-.*" />

I was expecting the more specific deeplink (/products) to be used instead of the most general.
I know that what is happening is that the first deeplink also matches the second deeplink, so it opens the first screen. But shouldn't the more specific deeplink match be used?
If I change the second deeplink to
    <deepLink
        android:id="@+id/organisationSeoDeeplink"
        app:uri=".*/organisation/{organisationId}/product/{productId}-.*" />

It works as expected. Is something missing?
